Deploy static retype files at vue route
I have a website set up using vue and now I want to add some documentation to it. I decided to use retype as its easy to write and format documentation. I use retype build to build the files and they work fine on a local webserver. Now I want to integrate these files into my website at a specific route (/docs). My website currently has 2 pages that are handled by the vue router:

Main landing page (<main_url>/)
Configuration (<main_url>/builder)

The generated documentation pages have routes themselves:

Documentation landing page (<doc_url>/)
First section (<doc_url>/first_section)
Nested section (<doc_url>/first_second/nested_section)

I essentially want to move the entire documentation pages to my main page at the <main_url>/docs route.

<doc_url>/ -> <main_url>/docs
<doc_url>/first_section -> <main_url>/docs/first_section
<doc_url>/first_second/nested_section ->
<main_url>/docs/first_section/nested_section

I tried just moving everything generated into the static folder but that messes with the redirection within the documentation.

I don't see no other way other than using some kind of reverse proxy like nginx

Hm, maybe that's not worth the effort. I am using aws amplify to directly build my website and I don't want to change that. Maybe I'll just register/add a subdomain like "wiki.<main_url>" and host the static site there without vue entirely.

Yes, in that case, subdomain is more appropriate
